# Difference between “generate” and “create”

Tags: word-usage, meaning

What is the difference between these two sentences:

- The new development will **generate** 1,500 new jobs
- The new development will **create** 1,500 new jobs

Comment: They seem about the same to me.

Comment: Yes, they have the same meaning.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is really a question of immediacy.

If I build a factory that offers employment to 1,500 workers, I create those jobs.

But if, as in the motor industry, I build a factory that offers employment to fewer workers, but leads to subsidiary industries that supply the factory with parts and to shops and restaurants that serve the workers' needs, the factory's activities generate the additional jobs.

That's to say that the building of the factory leads indirectly, rather than directly, to the additional jobs. The other industries and services are dependent for their existence on the factory.

Answer (score 0):

Normally "generate" emphasizes a mechanical process, and "create" emphasizes, well, creativity. That distinction doesn't really come into play in the example you posted, so there is little difference between your 2 sentences.